# bootstrap: making sidebar-nav acting as Accordion collapse all when opening a new one

Tags: jquery, accordion

this may be a very simple issue for some of you, however I cannot figure it out how can I make the all sidebar-nav to collapse when I click to a new one so only one remains expanded at a time. (actually I have to replicate the behavior of accordion)

this is pure bootstrap. I suppose CSS can handle it well, otherwise I am willing to use jQuery to collapse all somehow and after that to open only the clicked tab.

thanks a lot!

```
<!-- 1st side bar nav -->
<ul id="sidebar-nav" class="sidebar-nav margin-bottom-30px">
    <li class="list-group-item has-submenu">
        <a href="#" align="center" class="submenu-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="sidebar-nav"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> TEXT </a>
        <ul id="ID1" class="list-unstyled collapse submenu ">
            <li>
                some list
            </li>
            <li>
                some list.
            </li>
            <li>
                some list
            </li>
            <li>
                some list.
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>       
</ul>

<!-- 2nd side bar nav -->
<ul id="sidebar-nav" class="sidebar-nav margin-bottom-30px">
    <li class="list-group-item has-submenu">
        <a href="#" align="center" class="submenu-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="sidebar-nav"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> TEXT </a>
        <ul id="ID2" class="list-unstyled collapse submenu ">
            <li>
                some list
            </li>
            <li>
                some list.
            </li>
            <li>
                some list
            </li>
            <li>
                some list.
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>       
</ul>

some listsome list.

<!-- 20th side bar nav -->
<ul id="sidebar-nav" class="sidebar-nav margin-bottom-30px">
    <li class="list-group-item has-submenu">
        <a href="#" align="center" class="submenu-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="sidebar-nav"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> TEXT </a>
        <ul id="ID3" class="list-unstyled collapse submenu ">
            <li>
                some list
            </li>
            <li>
                some list.
            </li>
            <li>
                some list
            </li>
            <li>
                some list.
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>       
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.sidebar-nav').on('click', function () {
  $(this).animate({
    width: '400px'
  }, slow);

  $(this).siblings('.sidebar-nav').animate({
    width: '0px'
  }, slow, function () { $(this).fadeOut(); });
});
```